# IK Angle Constraints Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to set angle constraints for body parts in Swift 2.0.

I have tried to automatically set them in the scene editor under IK Constraints and this failed.

I subsequently set them in the code:

```
  lowerArmBack.reachConstraints?.lowerAngleLimit = 0
    lowerArmBack.reachConstraints?.upperAngleLimit = CGFloat(10)
```

Neither has worked (with or without CGFloat). I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/80917/sprite-kit-inverse-kinematics-swift but have stumbled in to issues since the Swift update.

Essentially I want to limit angles to prevent the arms moving in all 360 degrees but this isn't happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a zRotation constraint with a range for the body part you want:

```
let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: CGFloat(0).degreesToRadians(),
        upperLimit: CGFloat(160).degreesToRadians())
let rotationConstraint = SKConstraint.zRotation(range)
lowerArmFront.constraints = [rotationConstraint]
```

Regarding the tutorial, I'm actually working on it's update fixing the issue.

You can also add a SKReachConstraint in the following way:

```
lowerLeg.reachConstraints = SKReachConstraints(lowerAngleLimit: CGFloat(-45).degreesToRadians(), upperAngleLimit: 0)
    upperLeg.reachConstraints = SKReachConstraints(lowerAngleLimit: CGFloat(-45).degreesToRadians(), upperAngleLimit: CGFloat(160).degreesToRadians())
```

Hope it helps!